Maximal sub-$\mathbb{R}$-algebras of $\mathbb{R}[t]$
A proper $k$-algebra $M$ of $k[t]$ is a maximal sub-$k$-algebra of $k[t]$,
if there is no sub-$k$-algebra $A$ of $k[t]$ such that $M \subsetneq A \subsetneq k[t]$.
According to this MSE answer, together with the answer to this MSE post and a comment by David E Speyer to this MO post,
it seems that all maximal sub-$\mathbb{C}$-algebras of $\mathbb{C}[t]$
are of the form:
$\mathbb{C}[(t-a)(t-b),t(t-a)(t-b)]$, $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$.
Now I wish to concentrate on the following question, which is already included in previous posts of mine, but without comments:
Question: If we consider $\mathbb{R}[t]$ instead of $\mathbb{C}[t]$,
is it true that all maximal sub-$\mathbb{R}$-algebras of $\mathbb{R}[t]$
are of the form:
$\mathbb{R}[(t-a)(t-b),t(t-a)(t-b)]$, $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$?
Maybe the answer is no, because we may have problems with non-existing roots? and there are additional maximal sub-$\mathbb{R}$-algebras,
perhaps $\mathbb{R}[t^2+1,t(t^2+1)]$?
Thank you for any comments.

I fixed some typos. Some of them were quite substantial. Please double check.

@MartinBrandenburg, thank you very much! You are right in your corrections.
